# Random number generator method for linked list assignment

Tags: java, arrays, random, generator

So, I have to make a random number generator to get numbers ranging from 0 to 400.  I'm putting these into an array and then sorting them later on.  I just am not sure how to go about doing this.  I was given something along the lines of;

```
public int nextInt(400) //gives me errors
{
    random.setSeed(12345L);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size; i++)
    {
         val = random.nextInt(400);
         a[i] = val;
    }
}
```

I've already called the random class, since the directions indicated that.  I just don't know why this is not working.  It's giving me errors especially with the first part; class, interface, or enum expected.  Could somebody steer me in the right direction please?

Comment: Have you tried a very basic tutorial yet, like a "hello world" sample?  You don't seem to have the basics of how to write the most trivial of programs yet.

Comment: I have, yes.  I was just posting the piece I was given to work with.  I have never had to work with a random generator, so the entire concept is new to me.  I've looked it up and studied it, but it doesn't mesh well with what I was given.

Comment: The problems you're having with the code have nothing to do with you working with Random.  Put that complexity aside for now.  You haven't defined a class yet, and your method declaration has errors.  Both of these problems exist outside of introducing Random.  So fix those first, since you know how.

Comment: Here is one example of random function http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62

Comment: My mistake, I copied the wrong error.   It was saying illegal start of type.  I have never seen something declared as nextInt(400) with the number in the parenthesis, and it looks wrong to me.  It's just what is listed in the assignment and I'm unsure what to do with it.

Comment: It certainly is wrong; you can't put 400 in the declaration of your method.  You would do `nextInt(400)` when you want to *call* your method.

Comment: @RachelMoss my response below tries to shed some light onto that, but I strongly believe you should brush up on your basics before attempting this.

Answer (score 2):

Functions in Java (all programming languages) have "variables" in their definition.

You've got:

```
public int nextInt(400)
```

Over here, you want your 400 to be a value that is passed to the function.

Think of this as math. I'm sure you've dealt with something like `f(x) = 2 * x`. Here, x is the variable, and you "evaluate" f(x) with a value for x. Similarly, in programming, we'd have something like :

```
public int nextInt(int x)
```

As you see, our function defines x to be of type int. This is necessary in a language like Java because you're telling the compiler that this function will only accept integers for x.

Now that you've done that, you can use x as a variable in the body of your function.

Note that whenever you use a variable, it first has to be defined. A line such as:

```
int variable;
```

defines variable as an int.

Your program is missing these for `random`, `val`, `arr`, and `a`. Note here that `arr` and `a` are arrays (and somehow I get the feeling that they should not be two separate variables).

You should really brush up on variables definitions, arrays, and functions before attempting this question. Your best resource would be your textbook, because it'll explain everything in an organized, step-by-step manner. You can also try the many tutorials that are available online. If you have specific questions, you can always come back to StackOverflow and I'm sure you'll find help here.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this function within a class definition

Comment: I did.  I already have that implemented. The main problem I'm running into is with the "nextInt(400)" portion.  I'm unsure why.  That's how it was written in my assignment.

Comment: @Rachel: If you already have that implemented, you should update your question as the code you give, and the error message you report in your question suggest that you haven't declared the function within a class.  You need to give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (a self-contained piece of code that exactly reproduces the problem you want help solving).

Answer (score 0):

even you have specified :

```
public int nextInt(400)
```

in this line function returns **int** and in your whole body u didn't have any return statement.

and yes as Kshitij Mehata suggested dont use 400 directly as value use variable over there.

this should be your function:

```
public int[] nextInt(int x) //gives me errors
    {
        random.setSeed(12345L);
        int[] a=new int[arr.size];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size; i++)
        {
             val = random.nextInt(400);
             a[i] = val;
        }
        return a;
    }
```

even there is some issue with **arr** from where this **arr** come?

Comment: Since the OP is trying to learn programming and this is homework, its best not to give them the code. Rather, explain the steps and let them get to the solution themselves.